# Moving Git to another folder, but I've got a problem

Tags: python-3.x, git

My git was init in folder  ~/ryan/pythonproject/  and then later on I started using PyCharm and it created a venv for the project after importing. So now I have:

~/ryan/pythonproject/venv/

The first directory has my original work on the project, and then it appears I have a duplicate of my work under the venv folder.

Whenever I commit/add/push it does the original folder as well as the venv folder.

What I would like to do is have Git stop monitoring the original folder and only have git under the venv folder only. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Something else is wrong here. Don't try to do that.

Comment: How do I solve this though? Like, I don't want Git to monitor the original folder anymore. What's the best way to change this? Do I just "git init" in the venv folder and configure it like I did the original?

Comment: That would start a new repo. Presumably you have commits or other state you want to keep from your Git history (or else why are you using Git at all)? You can simply `git clone` a new instance in the place where you want it, and then abandon the old tree if it doesn't contain stuff you want anymore.

Comment: You know, that sounds like it would actually work for what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you for this. I'll give this a go.

Comment: Okay, quick question. All my project files are in the ~/ryan/pythonproject/venv folder already. If I clone it, it will make a new folder inside the venv folder which also has all my project files. How do I tell "git clone" to just overwrite the files in the folder that are there and continue using just the venv folder?

Comment: You really don't want Git inside your `venv`.

Comment: `git clone` into a place where the directory doesn't already exist (you can actually give it a different name if you pass a directory name after the source URL or spec; or move the old directory to a different name and then check out where it used to be) instead of making things complicated. If there are files you want to keep which are not currently in Git, you can move or copy them into place after the clone.

Comment: So, I created a new folder, git clone, and then just did 'git rm venv -r' (as I don't need that folder) and just told PyCharm to just open the folder with my work in it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop monitoring a folder you can put it to the .gitignore file. So i.e. you have:

- YourProject/venv/FolderA
- YourProject/venv/FolderB
- YourProject/FolderA
- YourProject/FolderB

Then just add the lower two to the .gitignore .
But please think about it whether this is really what you want. Usually it is the other way around. Keep your files and ignore the build folder.

Comment: In theory this sounds like a decent idea for sure. I think I might give it a try.